# DirectoryRef inside a Directory in WiX

Tags: wix

Consider I have a WiX Setup Library Project named MyLib.wixproj with 2 files that are shared with different installers. This project has the following (simplified) structure:

**MyLib.wxs:**

```
<Wix>
  <Fragment>

    <Feature Id="MySharedFeature" ...>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="MySharedCompGroup" />
    </Feature>

    <ComponentGroup Id="MySharedCompGroup" Directory="Directory_SharedFiles">
      <Component Id="SharedCompA" Guid="*">
        <File Id="SharedFileA Source="$(var.Source)fileA.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SharedCompB" Guid="*">
        <File Id="SharedFileB Source="$(var.Source)fileB.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <Directory Id="Directory_SharedFiles" Name="SharedFiles" />

  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

One of my installers (Setup Project) references the library this way:

**Product.wxs:**

```
<Wix>
  <Product>

    <FeatureRef Id="MySharedFeature" />

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

**Directories.wxs:**

```
<Wix>
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp">

          <!-- Here I want to add a reference to Directory_SharedFiles. -->

          <Directory Id="OtherFilesNotShared" Name="MoreFiles">
          </Directory>

        <Directory>
      </Directory> 
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
<Wix>
```

Inside the INSTALLDIR directory I want to add a DirectoryRef to `Directory_SharedFiles`, declared in my shared project. I tried using DirectoryRef but this tag doesn't exist as a child of Directory and it is not clear to me how to use `Directory Id="TARGETDIR"` inside the shared project, like this:

**MyLib.wxs:**

```
<!-- This code does not compile! -->
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="Directory_SharedFiles" Name="SharedFiles" />
</Directory>

</Fragment></Wix>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't nest the `DirectoryRef` element under a `Directory` element. Put it directly under the `Fragment` element. Read more on [DirectoryRef](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directoryref.html).

Build the directory structure in a shared WiX fragment instead of in each product separately.

Comment: I moved the directory structure to MyLib.wxs as shown at the end of the question but it doesn't work. Could you provide me an actual code snippet to solve it?

Comment: In the code you have, it is not clear where the directory Directory_SharedFiles is located on the target machine. Where are the shared files located? If in Program Files, you need to nest it under program files.